# sed remove '.' only in part of string

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I may be missing something basic here. I want to remove all the '.'s between the &'s in the following string. What regex should I be using in my sed?

```
**&v15.0&** something.anything abc.deg
**&v15.03.15&** something.anything abc.deg
**&v15.01.16.01&** something.anything abc.deg
**&v15.000.155.123.125&** something.anything abc.deg
```

to be modified to:

```
**&v150&** something.anything abc.deg
**&v150315&** something.anything abc.deg
**&v15011601&** something.anything abc.deg
**&v15000155123125&** something.anything abc.deg
```

There can be any number of '.'s withing the &'s, and I do not want the '.'s outside the &'s to be modified.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this oneliner:

```
awk -F'&' '{gsub(/\./,"",$2)}1' file
```

if you really want to do it with sed, and you have **Gnu sed**, you could do:

```
sed -r 's/([^&]*&)([^&]*)(&.*)/echo "\1"$(echo "\2"\|sed "s#\\.##g")"\3"/ge' file
```

test the sed line:

```
kent$  echo "**&v15.0&** something.anything abc.deg
**&v15.03.15&** something.anything abc.deg
**&v15.01.16.01&** something.anything abc.deg
**&v15.000.155.123.125&** something.anything abc.deg"|sed -r 's/([^&]*&)([^&]*)(&.*)/echo "\1"$(echo "\2"\|sed "s#\\.##g")"\3"/ge'
**&v150&** something.anything abc.deg
**&v150315&** something.anything abc.deg
**&v15011601&** something.anything abc.deg
**&v15000155123125&** something.anything abc.deg
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need. I am better off using awk for this one. Thanks.

Comment: @SkypeMeSM I added a sed (gnu sed) solution, you can pick the one you like.

Comment: although you accepted my answer, I would mention that, the two solutions in my answer work only if your string has only one `&....&` part. If your real text has more `&...&` part, the script needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular `sed` (also non-GNU) try:

```
sed -e :a -e 's/\(&.*\)\.\(.*&\)/\1\2/; ta' file
```